# Edge detection to identify artist style?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, edge-detection

I just wondered if anyone has every tried to use edge detection in regards to using it as a feature on its own for artist identification?

I know often most edge detection methods are used to then perform object detection with a database of objects, but cannot find whether or not edge detection can in isolation act as a feature!?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I'd suspect that edge detection can be used, but not on its own. Perhaps if you had enough samples you could determine the minute differences in edges to differentiate one artist from another, but I doubt it. Take many of the anime shows for example: the styles are very similar

Answer (score 1):

It takes a little bit more than basic edge detection, and having something better than just a photograph can make a big difference. Check out http://infolab.stanford.edu/~wangz/project/imsearch/ART/SP08/sp_vangogh.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's been some work on that (at L2CRMF that I know of, but others also).

Edge detection *per se* is not enough, though; you use it as a preliminary stage to identify features such as brush strokes, stroke vicinity, arcing, direction, average stroke length.

While talking shop, I was led to believe that this sort of analysis was a thankless task and much prone to errors; one of the many fields where human perception canniness still far outweighed automated processing. On the other hand this was back in 2003-2004, and things may have improved.

I have been able to find [this reference](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/patrick.flandrin/VanGogh.pdf), as well as [this other](http://proceedings.spiedigitallibrary.org/article.aspx?articleid=938473) which looks more promising.

Of historical interest only, Pliny (Naturalis Historia, XXXV.88, 81) reports of how Protogenes recognized a visitor to be the great painter Apelles from a line he had drawn, as it was so thin and perfect that such an absolute masterpiece could tally with no one else:

> *Ferunt Protogenem protinus, cum contemplatus esset subtilitatem,
>   dixisse Apellem venisse; adfirmavit enim tam absolutum opus non cadere
>   in alium*